# Why is my External javscript onclick not working

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have created a Javascript code that allows a person to select whether to view  a password or to hide
it. Everything was working perfectly until I decided to make the Javascript external.now when I click the show button it is not responsive.
What could be the issue?
HTML

```
<input type="password" id="password" oninput="display()" 
placeholder="Password">
<div id='disp'></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function display(){
var button=document.getElementById('password').value;
var button2=document.getElementById('password');

if(button.length>0 && button2.type==='password')
{
    document.getElementById('disp').innerHTML="<button  id='show' 
class='buton'onclick='myFunction()'><b>SHOW</b></button>";

}
else if(button.length>0 && button2.type==='text')
{
    document.getElementById('disp').innerHTML="<button  id='show' 
class='buton'onclick='myFunction()'><b>HIDE</b></button>";
}
else
{
   document.getElementById('disp').innerHTML='';  
}
}

function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("password");
if (x.type === "password") {
x.type = "text";
  document.getElementById("show").innerHTML='<b>HIDE</b>';
} else {
x.type = "password";
document.getElementById("show").innerHTML='<b>SHOW</b>';
}
}
```

Comment: Where is your <script> tag in your html?

Comment: At the bottom of my page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call a function with parentheses like display() on oninput. Without parentheses you're not actually calling the function only giving reference to the function.

```js
function display(){
    var button=document.getElementById('password').value;
    var button2=document.getElementById('password');

    if(button.length>0 && button2.type==='password')
    {
        document.getElementById('disp').innerHTML="<button  id='button' class='buton'onclick='myFunction()'><b>SHOW</b></button>";

    }
    else if(button.length>0 && button2.type==='text')
    {
        document.getElementById('disp').innerHTML="<button  id='button' class='buton'onclick='myFunction()'><b>HIDE</b></button>";
    }
    else
    {
       document.getElementById('disp').innerHTML='';  
    }
}

function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("password");
    if (x.type === "password") {
        x.type = "text";
      document.getElementById("button").innerHTML='<b>HIDE</b>';
    } else {
        x.type = "password";
        document.getElementById("button").innerHTML='<b>SHOW</b>';
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="password" id="password" oninput="display()" placeholder="Password">
<div id='disp'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks.And is there a way I can use an event listener.I've tried 
    document.getElementById("show").addEventListener("click", myfunction); and its not 
    working

Comment: I dont't find any id with "show" maybe that is the reason it is not working . Here is the solution for your another query. I have updated code here with addEventListener. You need to call this inside display() function.  https://jsfiddle.net/ajc3t7uL/

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the display function with brackets `()` in the `oninput`.

So don't do `display`, but `display()` instead.

It's like you evaluating JS code.

Writing `display` would return the function, but would not be called.

Comment: Thanks.And is there a way I can use an event listener.I've tried document.getElementById("show").addEventListener("click", myfunction); and its not working

Comment: When you change the innerHTML, you need to add the eventListener to the button again. So don't change the innerHTML of the div, but the button's instead.